# Mutex is lock but other threads are entering in critical section

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, mutex

We have studied that if we dealing with multi-threaded problems then we use one of thread synchronizing method called mutex which allows to lock critical section so that other threads do not interfere and goes into block state until mutex unlocks the critical section.

But I am doing this thing in my program but the output of this program is not matches with the concept of mutex. If I am wrong so correct me.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX 10 

pthread_mutex_t the_mutex;
pthread_cond_t condc, condp;
int toConsume=0;
int i;

void* consumer(void *ptr) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex);
while(i<MAX)
{
    /* protect buffer */
    while (toConsume <= 0) /* If there is nothing in the buffer then  wait */
    {
        printf("Waiting Thread id:%lu \n",pthread_self());
        pthread_cond_wait(&condc, &the_mutex);
    }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex); /* release the buffer */

    sleep(2);

   pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex); /* protect buffer */
   toConsume--;
   i++;
 }
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex); /* release the buffer */
 pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
pthread_t pro, con[3];
pthread_mutex_init(&the_mutex, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&condc, NULL); /* Initialize consumer condition variable */
pthread_cond_init(&condp, NULL); /* Initialize producer condition variable */

// Create the threads

for(int i=0 ;i<3;i++)
pthread_create(&con[i], NULL, consumer, NULL);

for(int i=0 ;i<3;i++)
pthread_join(con[i], NULL);

return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ ./ex
Waiting Thread id:140580582618880 
Waiting Thread id:140580574226176 
Waiting Thread id:140580565833472
```

All thread enters into critical section even the mutex remain its lock.

Comment: Tell me what `pthread_cond_wait` does.

Comment: It will wait for some condition to become true by using signaling form other process or thread.

Comment: Locking a mutex *inside* a loop with the corresponding unlock *outside* the loop is usually a bad idea -- in your `consumer()` function, if the `while(i<MAX)` loop body repeats, you'll attempt to lock `the_mutex` while it's already locked (which you shouldn't do).

Comment: Mistakenly putted it into the loop.

Comment: @suleman Is that *all* it does? (Hint: No)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `pthread_cond_wait` will unlock the held mutex while the thread is waiting. This allows another thread to enter the critical section.

The purpose of using `pthread_cond_wait` is that the thread needs to wait for some condition to become true before really performing the work inside the critical section. To test the condition in the first place requires locking the mutex. But, if the condition is false, it must wait for some event to make the condition true. If it waits with the lock held, no other thread will be able to update the state for the condition to become true, since updating the condition will also require locking the same mutex.

Thus, when waiting on a condition variable, the mutex is unlocked to allow another thread to grab the lock to perform something that would make the condition true.

As an example, consider a job queue. A thread will lock a mutex to get a job from the queue. However, if the queue is empty, it must wait for a job to appear in the queue. This is the condition that is must wait on, and a condition variable can be used for that purpose. When it calls `pthread_cond_wait` on the condition variable, the associated mutex is unlocked.

Another thread wishes to place a job into the queue. That thread can lock the mutex, add the job to the queue, signal the condition variable, then unlock the mutex.

When the condition variable is signaled, the waiting thread is woken up and `pthread_cond_wait` returns with the lock on the mutex held again. It detects that the queue is non-empty, and can enter the critical section of dequeueing a job from the queue.

Comment: This explanation clears my concept but is there any way to stop entering other threads in the critical section even the other thread is waiting for some condition to become true.

Comment: @suleman: They are stopped, since they have to wait for the same condition to become true.

Comment: Now let suppose all the threads are in waiting condition and suddenly a job arrives into the queue which have some waiting time here condition becomes true and one thread  take this job and perform some waiting by using sleep(waiting_time) function ,at this moment another job arrives into the queue and again condition becomes true through signaling then at this moment second thread will also take first job which is serving by first thread. Please clear this misunderstanding.

Comment: @suleman: The critical section removes the first job from the queue. Any subsequent thread that enters the critical section would not see that job.

Comment: @suleman: Only one thread can hold a lock on a mutex at a time, so even if multiple threads wake up on the condition variable, each can only return from `pthread_cond_wait` one at a time, as the mutex becomes lockable.